# time in a looping function is not changing

Tags: python

I want to make a program, that runs a function every minute, which function prints out the current time. I saw another thread on StackOverflow about how to call a function every 60 seconds. I used that method, but the time in the output file does not change.

Here's the code:

```
import time
import datetime

starttime = time.time()
now = datetime.datetime.now()

timeout = 60.0

def repeated_function():
    time = now.time()
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as file:
        file.write('time: ' + str(time) + '\n')

while True:
    repeated_function()
    time.sleep(timeout - ((time.time() - starttime) % timeout))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`now` doesn't return an object that updates itself continually. It returns an immutable `datetime` object that never changes.

You need to call `now` every time you want the current time:

```
def repeated_function():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()  # Call it to return the current time
    time = now.time()
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as file:
        file.write('time: ' + str(time) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move one line. (Moving the `now = ...` line down into the loop.)

```
import time
import datetime

starttime = time.time()


timeout = 60.0

def repeated_function():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time = now.time()
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as file:
        file.write('time: ' + str(time) + '\n')

while True:
    repeated_function()
    time.sleep(timeout - ((time.time() - starttime) % timeout))
```